# How to count make an SQL based on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables and Im trying to count the number of likes per user on all his/her post.

**USER TABLE**

```
id  name    
1   John    
2   Joe
```

**POSTS TABLE**

```
id  user_id     post_title
1   1           Some Title
2   1           Another Title
3   2           Yeah Title
```

**LIKES TABLE**

```
id  post_id 
1   1   
2   1   
3   1   
4   2   
5   3
```

My expected output is

```
ID LIKES
1  4
2  1
```

Im kinda stuck with the code below. I don't know how to add and count the likes table.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
INNER JOIN posts
ON user.id = posts.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the join to the LIKES table and then use `GROUP BY` to group by the user ID and `COUNT()` all of the records for that user...

```
SELECT user.id, COUNT(likes.id)
    FROM user
    INNER JOIN posts ON user.id = posts.user_id
    INNER JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id
    GROUP BY user.id
```

If you want to list people who don't have posts or likes, then you should use outer joins (so change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN) so that these users show up.

Answer (score 0):

For your desired result, you don't need the `user` table.  You can simply do:

```
SELECT p.user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM posts p JOIN
     likes l
     ON l.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.user_id;
```

The only information you are taking from users is the `id`, which is already in `posts`.  This assumes that all the `user_id` values in `posts` are valid, but that seems like a very reasonable assumption.